# MySQL / SQLAlchemy — JOIN on REGEX substring match between columns

Tags: mysql, regex, join, sqlalchemy, substring

I'd like to join (e.g. `LEFT JOIN`) following two tables upon a match of the main URL substring (ignoring `https://www.`)

1. first just using MySQL
2. then also implemented in SQLAlchemy

#### For example:

```
https://www.example.com/path1/  =matches=  https://example.com/path1/
```

but (http vs https)

```
http://www.example.com/path1/  =!does not match!=  https://example.com/path1/
```

#### First_Table

| id | Page | Visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | https: // www. example .com/path1/ | 164 |
| 1 | https: // www. example .com/path2/ | 4685 |
| 2 | https: // www. example .com/ | 12005 |

##### Second_Table

| id | Page | Visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | https: // example .com/path1/ | 546 |
| 8 | https: // example .com/path2/ | 4689 |
| 9 | https: // example .com/ | 8466 |

A regex, that captures the main substring is for example `(?<=https://)(?:www\.)?(.+)`

How would you approach this? What is the proper **MySQL syntax** and how can it be implemented with **SQLAlchemy**?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not a SQL specialist and not sure what you want to do but I would do the following:

1. Decline one table by replacing `//www.example.com` by `//example.com` or the inverse (`//example.com` by `//www.example.com`) so that both tables have a similar page URL for your comparaison.
2. Create an union of this declined table with the other one.
3. Group by page URL so that we can sum the visits.

The SQL code:

```sql
SELECT
  Page,
  SUM(Visits) AS `Total_Visits`
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      First_Table t1
    UNION
      (
        SELECT
          t2.id,
          REPLACE(t2.Page, '//example.com', '//www.example.com') AS `Page`,
          t2.Visits
        FROM
          Second_Table t2
      )
  ) Union_Table
GROUP BY
  Page
```

Result:

| Page | Total_Visits |
| --- | --- |
| https://www.example.com/ | 20471 |
| https://www.example.com/path1/ | 710 |
| https://www.example.com/path2/ | 9374 |

You could add a sort on the page URL.

Test and play with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d14e11/32

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime, I have also arrived at just doing a regex replacement, so a direct comparison can be done. I'm still curious, if there is another way to pattern-match substrings.

Comment: It would be interesting to time the execution of the pattern-matching solution. I could imagine that it would be slower than using a simple replace. I preferred the UNION because the left join will only load data from the second table if it matches, so you'll lose some non-matching entries from both tables, leading to wrong statistics. That's why it's important to explain what you are trying to do with this data. In some cases the JOIN would be better and in some the UNION would be better.

Comment: @creative-resort: Could you post your solution? I think that the benefit of **giving the answer to everybody** is one of the main reason of stackoverflow.

Comment: It's basically the same as yours, just with a JOIN instead of a UNION.
The downvote on your answer is not from me, btw. I upvoted your answer, because it is a working pragmatic solution.